# Designing a modern platform in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm in the early stages of prototyping a Rails 3 application that will expose a public API. The site has three separate concerns which I am planning to split across three subdomains.

- **api.mysite.com**

  - The publicly exposed API.
- **admin.mysite.com**

  - The admin portal for creating blogs (using the public API).
- **x.mysite.com**

  - The public blog site created at **admin.mysite.com** where ***x*** is the name of the blog. This too will make use of the public API.
- All three will share domain objects. For example, you should be able to login to **admin.mysite.com** using an account you created on **api.mysite.com** or **x.mysite.com**.

### Questions

1. Should I attempt to build one rails application to handle all three concerns or should I split this in multiple applications each handling a specific concern?
2. What are the Pros & Cons of each?
3. Does anyone have any insight into how some of the larger sites ([basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/), [github](http://github.com/), [shopify](http://www.shopify.com/)) are organized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is fairly general so I'll try and answer in general terms.  And the fact that you mention "larger sites" leads me to the conclusion that you're concerned about scaling.

1. In the beginning it is definitely going to be easier to build one application - especially since the domain is shared.  You can do separate controllers for the various interfaces (api, html, etc) but with a shared back-end.  This will reduce code duplication and the complexity of keeping 3 apps in sync.  Also remember that you might change your mind about features based on user feedback and you want to be nimble enough to respond quickly.
2. The main benefit I can see of separating out three different deployables is that you can have an independent deploy schedule for each.  For example, a bug fix in the api won't have to wait for admin to be ready to deploy.  Or that you can have separate teams working in parallel.
3. If you're careful about what you keep in your session you'll be able to deploy multiple instances of your application on multiple servers, pointing at the same database (a.k.a. horizontal scaling).  Each of these instances are identical to the others and a load balancer (either dedicated hardware or virtual) directs traffic between them.  Eventually this approach runs out of steam when your database can't handle the load.  At that point you can look at more caching, sharding, no-sql and all sorts of clever scaling techniques.

Most (but not all) larger sites end up doing some sort of horizontal scaling with some sharding of data.

All told, focus on getting a useful application to your users.  If things take off you can worry about scaling.  More applications fail because the user experience is awful rather than not being able to scale.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It sounds like creating a single app is the best idea for now. In order for that to work I'm guessing I would create a controller for each of the three concepts and forward requests to the correct controller based on the subdomain?